# How do I create a matrix of pair wise values for a list of elements each having a scale value?

Tags: python

I have a file containing a list of names with a scale value for each. I need to produce a matrix, that is the product of values for each pair of names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('candegree.csv', usecols=[0, 5], nrows=26)  # if using the csv file
df.head()
```

#### Data [candegree.csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OYy6HLXD2vAF4MEPBJd_s3yDFRT9pZ_bGVP6-HxW5uI/edit?usp=sharing):

- `Candidate` and `Relations` are the columns of interest.

```
    Candidate  Relations
       bennet       0.52
        biden       0.92
       blasio       0.66
       booker       0.84
      bullock       0.79
    buttigieg       0.75
       castro       0.74
      delaney       0.59
      gabbard       0.77
   gillibrand       0.78
       harris       0.88
 hickenlooper       0.79
       inslee       0.70
    klobuchar       0.77
      moulton       0.71
      orourke       0.80
         ryan       0.79
      sanders       0.88
       steyer       0.73
     swalwell       0.81
        trump       0.91
        walsh       0.69
       warren       0.86
         weld       0.53
   williamson       0.69
         yang       0.81
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code produces the product of each pair of names.

- For cases with the product of a name and itself, the value is set to `np.NaN`

  - Remove `df[name].loc[name] = np.NaN` if you want that product
  - `type(np.NaN)` = `float`, therefore, filling with `np.NaN` ensures the ability to perform column wise calculations, without experiencing issues with `type`
  - Alternatively, setting `df[name].loc[name] = None`, should work too, which precludes the necessity of using `numpy`
- Set `Candidate` as `index`, then use `.loc` to find the `Relations` coefficient for the individual name, which can be used for column wise multiplication.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('candegree.csv', usecols=[0, 5], nrows=26)

df.set_index('Candidate', inplace=True)

for name in df.index:
    df[name] = df.Relations * df.Relations.loc[name]
    df[name].loc[name] = np.NaN

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

#### Output:

```py
    Candidate  Relations  bennet   biden  blasio  booker  bullock  buttigieg  castro  delaney  gabbard  gillibrand  harris  hickenlooper  inslee  klobuchar  moulton  orourke    ryan  sanders  steyer  swalwell   trump   walsh  warren    weld  williamson    yang
       bennet       0.52     NaN  0.4784  0.3432  0.4368   0.4108     0.3900  0.3848   0.3068   0.4004      0.4056  0.4576        0.4108   0.364     0.4004   0.3692    0.416  0.4108   0.4576  0.3796    0.4212  0.4732  0.3588  0.4472  0.2756      0.3588  0.4212
        biden       0.92  0.4784     NaN  0.6072  0.7728   0.7268     0.6900  0.6808   0.5428   0.7084      0.7176  0.8096        0.7268   0.644     0.7084   0.6532    0.736  0.7268   0.8096  0.6716    0.7452  0.8372  0.6348  0.7912  0.4876      0.6348  0.7452
       blasio       0.66  0.3432  0.6072     NaN  0.5544   0.5214     0.4950  0.4884   0.3894   0.5082      0.5148  0.5808        0.5214   0.462     0.5082   0.4686    0.528  0.5214   0.5808  0.4818    0.5346  0.6006  0.4554  0.5676  0.3498      0.4554  0.5346
       booker       0.84  0.4368  0.7728  0.5544     NaN   0.6636     0.6300  0.6216   0.4956   0.6468      0.6552  0.7392        0.6636   0.588     0.6468   0.5964    0.672  0.6636   0.7392  0.6132    0.6804  0.7644  0.5796  0.7224  0.4452      0.5796  0.6804
      bullock       0.79  0.4108  0.7268  0.5214  0.6636      NaN     0.5925  0.5846   0.4661   0.6083      0.6162  0.6952        0.6241   0.553     0.6083   0.5609    0.632  0.6241   0.6952  0.5767    0.6399  0.7189  0.5451  0.6794  0.4187      0.5451  0.6399
    buttigieg       0.75  0.3900  0.6900  0.4950  0.6300   0.5925        NaN  0.5550   0.4425   0.5775      0.5850  0.6600        0.5925   0.525     0.5775   0.5325    0.600  0.5925   0.6600  0.5475    0.6075  0.6825  0.5175  0.6450  0.3975      0.5175  0.6075
       castro       0.74  0.3848  0.6808  0.4884  0.6216   0.5846     0.5550     NaN   0.4366   0.5698      0.5772  0.6512        0.5846   0.518     0.5698   0.5254    0.592  0.5846   0.6512  0.5402    0.5994  0.6734  0.5106  0.6364  0.3922      0.5106  0.5994
      delaney       0.59  0.3068  0.5428  0.3894  0.4956   0.4661     0.4425  0.4366      NaN   0.4543      0.4602  0.5192        0.4661   0.413     0.4543   0.4189    0.472  0.4661   0.5192  0.4307    0.4779  0.5369  0.4071  0.5074  0.3127      0.4071  0.4779
      gabbard       0.77  0.4004  0.7084  0.5082  0.6468   0.6083     0.5775  0.5698   0.4543      NaN      0.6006  0.6776        0.6083   0.539     0.5929   0.5467    0.616  0.6083   0.6776  0.5621    0.6237  0.7007  0.5313  0.6622  0.4081      0.5313  0.6237
   gillibrand       0.78  0.4056  0.7176  0.5148  0.6552   0.6162     0.5850  0.5772   0.4602   0.6006         NaN  0.6864        0.6162   0.546     0.6006   0.5538    0.624  0.6162   0.6864  0.5694    0.6318  0.7098  0.5382  0.6708  0.4134      0.5382  0.6318
       harris       0.88  0.4576  0.8096  0.5808  0.7392   0.6952     0.6600  0.6512   0.5192   0.6776      0.6864     NaN        0.6952   0.616     0.6776   0.6248    0.704  0.6952   0.7744  0.6424    0.7128  0.8008  0.6072  0.7568  0.4664      0.6072  0.7128
 hickenlooper       0.79  0.4108  0.7268  0.5214  0.6636   0.6241     0.5925  0.5846   0.4661   0.6083      0.6162  0.6952           NaN   0.553     0.6083   0.5609    0.632  0.6241   0.6952  0.5767    0.6399  0.7189  0.5451  0.6794  0.4187      0.5451  0.6399
       inslee       0.70  0.3640  0.6440  0.4620  0.5880   0.5530     0.5250  0.5180   0.4130   0.5390      0.5460  0.6160        0.5530     NaN     0.5390   0.4970    0.560  0.5530   0.6160  0.5110    0.5670  0.6370  0.4830  0.6020  0.3710      0.4830  0.5670
    klobuchar       0.77  0.4004  0.7084  0.5082  0.6468   0.6083     0.5775  0.5698   0.4543   0.5929      0.6006  0.6776        0.6083   0.539        NaN   0.5467    0.616  0.6083   0.6776  0.5621    0.6237  0.7007  0.5313  0.6622  0.4081      0.5313  0.6237
      moulton       0.71  0.3692  0.6532  0.4686  0.5964   0.5609     0.5325  0.5254   0.4189   0.5467      0.5538  0.6248        0.5609   0.497     0.5467      NaN    0.568  0.5609   0.6248  0.5183    0.5751  0.6461  0.4899  0.6106  0.3763      0.4899  0.5751
      orourke       0.80  0.4160  0.7360  0.5280  0.6720   0.6320     0.6000  0.5920   0.4720   0.6160      0.6240  0.7040        0.6320   0.560     0.6160   0.5680      NaN  0.6320   0.7040  0.5840    0.6480  0.7280  0.5520  0.6880  0.4240      0.5520  0.6480
         ryan       0.79  0.4108  0.7268  0.5214  0.6636   0.6241     0.5925  0.5846   0.4661   0.6083      0.6162  0.6952        0.6241   0.553     0.6083   0.5609    0.632     NaN   0.6952  0.5767    0.6399  0.7189  0.5451  0.6794  0.4187      0.5451  0.6399
      sanders       0.88  0.4576  0.8096  0.5808  0.7392   0.6952     0.6600  0.6512   0.5192   0.6776      0.6864  0.7744        0.6952   0.616     0.6776   0.6248    0.704  0.6952      NaN  0.6424    0.7128  0.8008  0.6072  0.7568  0.4664      0.6072  0.7128
       steyer       0.73  0.3796  0.6716  0.4818  0.6132   0.5767     0.5475  0.5402   0.4307   0.5621      0.5694  0.6424        0.5767   0.511     0.5621   0.5183    0.584  0.5767   0.6424     NaN    0.5913  0.6643  0.5037  0.6278  0.3869      0.5037  0.5913
     swalwell       0.81  0.4212  0.7452  0.5346  0.6804   0.6399     0.6075  0.5994   0.4779   0.6237      0.6318  0.7128        0.6399   0.567     0.6237   0.5751    0.648  0.6399   0.7128  0.5913       NaN  0.7371  0.5589  0.6966  0.4293      0.5589  0.6561
        trump       0.91  0.4732  0.8372  0.6006  0.7644   0.7189     0.6825  0.6734   0.5369   0.7007      0.7098  0.8008        0.7189   0.637     0.7007   0.6461    0.728  0.7189   0.8008  0.6643    0.7371     NaN  0.6279  0.7826  0.4823      0.6279  0.7371
        walsh       0.69  0.3588  0.6348  0.4554  0.5796   0.5451     0.5175  0.5106   0.4071   0.5313      0.5382  0.6072        0.5451   0.483     0.5313   0.4899    0.552  0.5451   0.6072  0.5037    0.5589  0.6279     NaN  0.5934  0.3657      0.4761  0.5589
       warren       0.86  0.4472  0.7912  0.5676  0.7224   0.6794     0.6450  0.6364   0.5074   0.6622      0.6708  0.7568        0.6794   0.602     0.6622   0.6106    0.688  0.6794   0.7568  0.6278    0.6966  0.7826  0.5934     NaN  0.4558      0.5934  0.6966
         weld       0.53  0.2756  0.4876  0.3498  0.4452   0.4187     0.3975  0.3922   0.3127   0.4081      0.4134  0.4664        0.4187   0.371     0.4081   0.3763    0.424  0.4187   0.4664  0.3869    0.4293  0.4823  0.3657  0.4558     NaN      0.3657  0.4293
   williamson       0.69  0.3588  0.6348  0.4554  0.5796   0.5451     0.5175  0.5106   0.4071   0.5313      0.5382  0.6072        0.5451   0.483     0.5313   0.4899    0.552  0.5451   0.6072  0.5037    0.5589  0.6279  0.4761  0.5934  0.3657         NaN  0.5589
         yang       0.81  0.4212  0.7452  0.5346  0.6804   0.6399     0.6075  0.5994   0.4779   0.6237      0.6318  0.7128        0.6399   0.567     0.6237   0.5751    0.648  0.6399   0.7128  0.5913    0.6561  0.7371  0.5589  0.6966  0.4293      0.5589     NaN
```

Comment: I would suggest to use df.corr() for correlation matrices.

Comment: @MarcoD.G. The OP asks for the `product` of each `Candidate` with each of the other `Candidates`, not the correlation between them.